# Python recognize most likely to occur in a repeating pattern of letters/numbers

Tags: python

I'm looking for a Python solution to extract from a series of letters/numbers, the most repeating pattern which comes with an outcome and a specific length.

Problem: When is `search` more likely to occur given a 4 digit block (Block Length) of digits/letters? (So the string has to **END** with `search`)

Example:

```
Input: 0010000101010001011010011101001101000011100010100101010111
Search: 1
Block Length: 4
---
Answer: 0101
Appeared: 5 times
```

In the above case "1" is more likely to appear when 010 comes before 1.

001000 [010**1**] 0100 [010**1**] 1010011101001101000011100 [010**1**] 0 [010**1**] [010**1**] 11

So the answer is `0101` an it appeared `5` times.

**NOTE**:
This could return `0001` but that only appeared 4 times while `0101` appeared 5 times.

Changing the length would result in:

```
Input: 0010000101010001011010011101001101000011100010100101010111 (same as above)
Search: 1
Block Length: 5
---
Answer: 00101
Appeared: 4 times
```

Because:

00100 [0010**1**] 010 [0010**1**] 101001110100110100001110 [0010**1**][0010**1**] 010111

**NOTE**:
The second example could return `00001` but that only appeared 2 times while `00101` appeared 4 times.

If there are multiple outcomes ie: `0101` and `0111` have the same presence, both outcome should be showing.

---

I'm at the point where I can find the more repeating string, but I don't know how to give the length:

```
def find_most_repetitive_substring(string):
    max_counter = 1
    position, substring_length, times = 0, 0, 0
    for i in range(len(string)):
        for j in range(len(string) - i):
            counter = 1
            if j == 0:
                continue
            while True:
                if string[i + counter * j: i + (counter + 1) * j] != string[i: i + j] or i + (counter + 1) * j > len(string):
                    if counter > max_counter:
                        max_counter = counter
                        position, substring_length, times = i, j, counter
                    break
                else:
                    counter += 1
    return string[position: position + substring_length * times]
```

Comment: Why is the first example 0101 (5 times) and not 1010 (6 times) ? - `0010000 [1010] 1000101 [1010] 011 [1010] 01 [1010] 000111000 [1010] 0 [1010] 10111`

Comment: and your second example I think should be 5 - not 4.... eg: `001000010 [10100] 0101 [10100] 11 [10100] 1 [10100] 00111000 [10100] 101010111`

Comment: Actually they are both correct. You are not taking into account the "search". They need to END in 1 because the "search" parameter is "1".

Comment: Ahh... so that's what you mean by *In the above case "1" is more likely to appear when 010 comes before 1.* - so the search is basically a block "ends with" ?

Comment: Correct, Ends with, let me point that out in the question. Tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used `re` here as you're dealing with text but you can use over techiques to create blocks of N length with overlaps...

```
import re

def f(text, search, length):
    # Get unique blocks of length N - including overlaps
    overlaps = set(re.findall(f'(?=(.{{{length}}}))', text))
    # Priotise those ending with length, then the count of non-overlapping and then include the block itself
    return max((block.endswith(search), text.count(block), block) for block in overlaps)

S = '0010000101010001011010011101001101000011100010100101010111'

f(S, '1', 4)
# (True, 5, '0101')
f(S, '1', 5)
#(True, 4, '00101')
```

Comment: This is great. You only have to change "s" at the end of "overlaps" and replace it with "text". The rest is great

Answer (score 1):

This might help you with part of your question (i.e., getting the counts); iterating and storing things in a lookup table (dictionary):

```
def find_most_repetitive_substring(string, substring_length, ending='1'):
  """
  Finds the most repetive substring in a given string.
  :param string: String to search for repetitions.
  :param substring_length: Length of the substring to search for.
  :param ending: character that pattern must end with. default is '1'.
  :return: Most repetitive substring and its number of occurrences.
  """
  substring_count = {}
  for i in range(len(string) - substring_length + 1):
      substring = string[i:i + substring_length]
      if substring[-1] == ending: # added for ending
          if substring in substring_count:
              substring_count[substring] += 1
          else:
              substring_count[substring] = 1
  max_substr = max(substring_count, key=substring_count.get)
  return max_substr, substring_count[max_substr]



find_most_repetitive_substring('0010000101010001011010011101001101000011100010100101010111', 4)
```

And if you want to get all the keys with the max val, you can just return a list, changing the last lines to something like this:

```
max_substr = max(substring_count, key=substring_count.get)
max_substrs = [k for k, v in substring_count.items() if v == substring_count[max_substr]]
return max_substrs, substring_count[max_substr]
```

Comment: This is promising, but the "search" part is missing. Meaning I need to extract those only where it ENDS with "search"

Comment: Ah, I think I get it know. You could maybe add an extra parameter to the method, so its signature would be 

find_most_repetitive_substring(string, substring_length, ending)

and then nest the above if/else statement within something like this:

if substring[-1] == ending:

which will check that it matches the last specific character.

Comment: I'm poor in Python, could you edit the answer maybe?

Comment: yep, updated :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

def find_most_repetitive_substring(string, size, search):
    res = Counter([string[i:i+size] for i in range(len(string) - size)])
    return max(res, key=lambda x: (x.endswith(search), res.get(x)))
```

Example run:

```
inp = "0010000101010001011010011101001101000011100010100101010111"
s = find_most_repetitive_substring(inp, 4, "1")
print(s)  # 0101
```